# Nginx proxy_pass keeps redirecting to localhost

Tags: nginx

I am trying to set up a reverse proxy from my domain to `http://127.0.0.1:4000`. My issue is that whenever I try to open `https://example.com` (not the actual domain) in a browser, I just get redirected to `http://localhost` on my own machine. There is nothing listening on the server at `http://127.0.0.1:4000` yet. I am just trying to see the 504 error screen.

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
        }
}
```

The domain does point to this server. I am able to connect to the server via this domain, but when I view it in a browser I always get redirected to `http://localhost`.

EDIT: I just tried it in another browser and realized it was Chrome doing the redirect. The server works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I tried it in another browser and it worked fine. Chrome is just stuck redirecting me for some reason...

Comment: Clear your browser cache?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's actually the fault of the thing I'm trying to host on the other side of the proxy. It's API Umbrella, and it's putting out a 301 redirect to localhost. So even after I turned off the server, my browser still cached the redirect. So now I'm figuring out how to disable that garbage lol.

Comment: A 301 can be cached permanently. So, yeah, that ought to be fixed...

Answer (score 0):

`504 Gateway Timeout` error means that nginx was able to succesfully connect and send request to the `127.0.0.1:4000` server, but did not receive a response within expected time.

To see that error message, you need to have a server running on the port, and make it not send a reply within timeout specified in nginx configuration.

Comment: Actually no, there is no server running at port 4000 and nginx instantly shows the 504 error. It was just Chrome redirecting me.